# Grep Regex Captured Groups

Tags: regex, grep, sh

I've lines like below in a file

`[Lorem ipsum] - [ipsum23] - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.`

And I want to use `grep '[regex]'` to get the below results:

`[Lorem ipsum] - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.`

I've the below regex, but I'm not sure how to just use the captured groups with `grep`

`grep -oP '(\[[^\]]+\]).+\](.+)'`

I've tried:

`grep -oP '(\[[^\]]+\])\1.+\](.+)\2'`

`grep -oP '(\[[^\]]+\])\k.+\](.+)\2'`

`[^\-]*\-(?<=\-).*`

`(?<!\-).+(?=\-)` - Also tried using Lookaround to see if I can just get the beginning and the end and skip the middle part, but it didn't work as I expected

Or will using `sed` be better for this? Or a different approach to the regex?

Comment: What are the rules? You don't want the second bracketed string?

Comment: Why `sh`? I'd understand if you were targeting baseline POSIX or busybox, but `grep -P` means you're somewhere with libpcre and GNU grep, so you're not on a tiny little embedded platform where bash isn't practical.

Answer (score 0):

What about a pure BASH solution? Something like this:

```
s='[Lorem ipsum] - [ipsum23] - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'
if [[ $s =~ (.*)\ -\ (.*)\ -\ (.*) ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} - ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
fi
```

It results in:

```
[Lorem ipsum] - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is for selection, `sed` is for replacement. Simply match the part you want to get rid of and replace with nothing:

`echo "[Lorem ipsum] - [ipsum23] - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." | sed "s/ \[.*?\] -//"`

Output:
`[Lorem ipsum] - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aElbgM/1